# Making multiple ForEach-Object more efficient

Tags: powershell

```
$prcs = (Get-Process).MainModule.FileName|%{Get-AuthenticodeSignature$_}|Select Path,Status
$prcs|?{$_.status -eq "valid"}
$prcs|?{-not $_.status -eq "valid"}
```

How would I go about making the last two lines smaller and/or more efficient? Complete newbie here!

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do.. First one seems fine, second you can change to `$prcs | ? {$_.status -ne "valid"}`

Comment: Trying to make the code as small as possible, so I want to print both $prcs valid and not valid in an efficient way.

Comment: Are you trying to process each object one at a time, and do one thing if status equals valid but do a different thing if status not equals valid?

Comment: I wanted to sort by both Valid and Not Valid in alphabetic order, but in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running V4, you can use the `Split` option of the `Where()` method:

```
$Valid,$NotValid =  $prcs.where({$_.status -eq "valid"},'Split')
```

Comment: This is REALLY nice! Thank you!!